# How to make a div click-through but hover-able?

Tags: javascript, css, html, hover

I need to make a div so that when the cursor hovers over it then I can detect it (using javascript) but I want to make it so that you can click through the div to the elements underneath. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: @keune elements underneath are not necessarily childrens I suppose

Comment: Your question is not clear, what did you mean by underneath, post `HTML` code here.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements?

Comment: using `pointer-events: none` breaks the hover?

Comment: @JanDvorak yeah I tried pointer-events: none which allowed the clickthrough but it didn't recognise the hover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**
As far as I'm aware, and through my quick searches, I do not believe that you are able to do this, if you can it wouldn't be easy and or very practical I wouldn't think.

**old**

Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").on("hover", "div", function(){
         //do whatever you want on hover
    });

    $("body").on("click", "div .child-class", function(){
        //do whatever on click
    });
});
```

If this doesn't answer your question and do what you want, let me know what more specifically why it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I don't want to do anything specific when the div is clicked, I just want it to pretend as if the div located physically underneath it was clicked in the same position.

Comment: Oh I understand what you mean now, when you said, "you can click through the div to the elements underneath" I took it as meaning, clicking through a series of divs. But you just want to be able to click the elements with a z-index below another div. IE a clicking below a popup of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions for this depending on your problem.
I will start with some assumptions:
1. You are the owner of the page (you know what happens there);
2. You know what element is beneath the clicked element.

For this case check this code:

```
//function executed when you click on element with id: beneath
function clickOnBeneath() {
    alert("beneath click");
}

//function executed when you click on element with id: above
function clickOnAbove() {
    var beneathEl;
    beneathEl = document.getElementById("beneath");
    beneathEl.click();
}

//attach click event on element with id: above and beneath
function attachClickOnElements() {
    var aboveEl,
        beneathEl;
    aboveEl = document.getElementById("above");
    aboveEl.addEventListener("click", clickOnAbove, false);
    beneathEl = document.getElementById("beneath");
    beneathEl.addEventListener("click", clickOnBeneath, false);
}

attachClickOnElements();
```

and also working example: http://jsfiddle.net/darkyndy/xRupb/

If you don't know what element is beneath it then I will try to find some code as I wrote a couple of years back something like this, as start point you can check *getClientRects()* function that is available on HTML elements (documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getClientRects )